# how to find a string containing a square bracket?

Tags: php, regex, square-bracket

i'm using a regular expression to search for a bunch of keywords in a text.

All keywords are found but one: [DAM]Berlin. I know it contains a square bracket so i escaped it, but still, no luck. What am i doing wrong?

here is my php code.

The text to search for keywords:

```
$textToSearch= '<p><br>
Time ¦ emit LAb[au] <br>
<br>
[DAM]Berlin gallery<br>
<br>
Exhibition: February 21st - March 28th, 2009 <br>
<br>
Opening: Friday,  February 20th, 2009 7-9 pm <br>';
```

The regular expression:

```
$find='/(?![^<]+>)\b(generative art console|Game of Life|framework notations|framework|Floating numbers|factorial|f5x5x3|f5x5x1|eversion|A-plus|16n|\[DAM\]Berlin gallery)\b/s';
```

the replace Callback function:

```
function replaceCallback( $match )
{
      if ( is_array( $match ) )
      {
        $htmlVersion = htmlspecialchars( $match[1], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' );
        $urlVersion  = urlencode( $match[1] );
        return '<a class="tag" rel="tag-definition" title="Click to know more about ' . $htmlVersion . '" href="?tag=' . $urlVersion. '">'. $htmlVersion  . '</a>';
      }
      return $match;
}
```

and finally, the call:

```
$tagged_content = preg_replace_callback($find, 'replaceCallback',  $textToSearch);
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because `[` isn't a "word character", so `\b[` can't match `[` in the beginning of `[DAM]Berlin`. You probably need to change your regex to:

```
$find='/(?![^<]+>)(\b(?:generative art console|Game of Life|framework notations|framework|Floating numbers|factorial|f5x5x3|f5x5x1|eversion|A-plus|16n)|\[DAM\]Berlin gallery)\b/s';
```

---

**Edit:** From Daniel James's comment:

> This might be closer to the original intent, as it will still check that '[Dam]' doesn't follow a word character:
>
> ```
> $find='/(?![^<]+>)(?<!\w)(generative art console|Game of Life|framework notations|framework|Floating numbers|factorial|f5x5x3|f5x5x1|eversion|A-plus|16n|\[DAM\]Berlin gallery)\b/s';
> ```

Comment: i tried your suggestion however php returns a warning. Is there an alternative to the b flag?
here is the warning: 

preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 166

Comment: Remove the closing parenthese at the end \b)/s (this one)

Comment: This might be closer to the original intent, as it will still check that '[Dam]' doesn't follow a word character:

$find='/(?![^<]+>)(?<!\w)(generative art console|Game of Life|framework notations|framework|Floating numbers|factorial|f5x5x3|f5x5x1|eversion|A-plus|16n|\\[DAM\\]Berlin gallery)\b/s';

Comment: Amazingly, in the final code, Daniel 's suggestion is the one that works. Helen's suggestion somwhere broke the resulting text.
The fact that i'm searching for a lot of keywords might be the reason. Thanks to both of you anyway !

Comment: @pixeline: That must be the new capturing group I added... Turned it into a non-capturing one. But Daniel's variant should be more reliable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The first section of your Regex is '/(?![^<]+>)\b' so wouldn't it only match "[DAM]Berlin gallery" if the character before it was a '>'?

try:

```
$find='/(?![^<]+>)\b(generative art console|Game of Life|framework notations|framework|Floating numbers|factorial|f5x5x3|f5x5x1|eversion|A-plus|16n|\[DAM\]Berlin gallery)\b/sm'
```

That adds the m modifier to your regex so that it will ignore new lines

> http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html#8
>
> "[the m modifier] treats a string as having only a
> single newline character at the end,
> even if there are multiple new lines
> in our string."